# Drools rule language: strange behaviour with class fields

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I recently noticed some strange behaviour with drools rules. I had class HeartRate and it has the following fields:

```
int heartRate;
Date timeStamp;
String macAddress;
```

My rule file is the following:

```
import drools.HeartRate
import drools.Action

declare HeartRate
    @role(event)
end

rule "HEARTRATE RULE 1"
when
    $heartRate : HeartRate(heartRate >= 180) from entry-point "entryHeartRate"
then
    Action.handleAction(1,"Heart rate is to high!");
end
```

I want to change the field `heartRate` to `heartrate` and I change the field name in my rule also so that my new rule is now:

```
rule "HEARTRATE RULE 1"
when
    $heartRate : HeartRate(heartrate >= 180) from entry-point "entryHeartRate"
then
    Action.handleAction(1,"Heart rate is to high!");
end
```

But this gives errors namely that drools can't resolve the field `heartrate`. But when I change the rule back to the original so with `heartRate` it works event though such a field doesn't exist anymore. I get the following error:

```
[Unable to Analyse Expression heartrate >= 180:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: drools.HeartRate.heartrate()]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to compile drl".
[Near : {... heartrate >= 180 ....}]
             ^
[Line: 26, Column: 4] : [Rule name='HEARTRATE RULE 1']
]
    at drools.Main.initDrools(Main.java:53)
    at drools.Main.main(Main.java:39)
C:\Users\Tim Deweert\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes are supposed to follow the Java Beans specification, and Drools will try to locate `getSomeField` if you use `someField` in a constraint. It doesn't matter how the *private* instance field itself is called.

If the field is public, it will be used if the name matches. Otherwise a getter is used if its name matches according to the rule given above.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, I forgot to change the get/set methods of the field heartrate.